# Switching MX records on exchange server

Tags: email, dns, exchange-server, mx-record

So I'm migrating my small businesses email from an exchange (2010) server to office 365 (exchange 2013). Users have their accounts connected in outlook. If i have the identical setup on Office 365 (email addresses, passwords, userprinciplename all the same), will swapping over the MX records require users to re-add their mail to outlook or will it be zero config?

PS - I'm migrating their mail and setting up forwarding on their accounts so they don't lose any mail.

Answer (score 1):

Outlook does not use the MX record to connect to Exchange, the MX Record is only used for incoming mail from a third party.

Outlook connects to Exchange locally using the inernal hostname of the Exchange server, in an sbs environment this is SERVER.DOMAIN.LOCAL.

You could attempt to get around this my adding host records to all the PCs via group policy/script to point hostname to the new server but then the name of the server will change.

You will most likely have to reconfigure Outlook as certificates and encryption will change.

In the past for Exchange 2007 and 2010 you were given the Microsoft Office customisation tool to  create an MSP file that you could use to roll out an outlook profile using group policy but you will need to check if this is available to you.